# Scroll top applies when debugged in Firefox but not regularly

Tags: jquery

I have applied scroll top functionality in my website.

It works fine in **chrome** or **IE** , where as in **Firefox**, it doesn't work.

Under normal scenarios it doesn't applies, but when I debug over the line of code which scrolls to top it works.

This is the piece of code i have implemented for scrolling when the page loads.

```
$("#scrollDiv").scrollTop(Math.round(($('#div1').width() / 4)));
```

I am not able to figure out what could be the exact issue.

Comment: Impossible to know with this little information, you are only scrolling one element and based on another elements width. So you are not scrolling the whole page. Add more information to your question, relevant hmtl and css and create jsfiddle to showcase the problem.

Comment: jsfiddle example?